# How to Detect Hand Press on Android Screen

Tags: android, android-sensors, proximitysensor

I have a requirement that I have to count that At End of Day how many Time user kept Hand on Android Screen ?

So for that after googling I found that, there is proximity Sensor in Android which senses hand movement without touching screen. Proxymity Sensor is located somewhere on Top of Screen for Accessing object close to phone while attending and cancelling any calls

But I wanted to capture user hand press on Android Screen. What could be better solution ? or can my purpose be fully solved via proximity Sensor only ?

Comment: What do you mean by `user hand press`? partial press or full hand? if it is full, phones are out of your scope, right? If not, how will you distinguish a big touch area vs a real hand pressing? Proximity Sensor doesn't detect hand movement, it just detect how close something is (like your head or hand or anything in the same line). AFAIK, it only detects how close things are (if detectable).

Comment: In your case scenario, is there any difference between "how much time the user holds a touch using a finger" vs "how much time the user holds a touch with his full hand"??

Answer (score 1):

Proxymity Sensor is very rough and used to tell whether mobile device is close to something big as head.

You need to implement hooks for everything that user may touch, and increase your counter, that should be saved/restored when app goes to background and returns.

Note that you only can know about touches within your app.